# Whats is major impact when implements redis cache and varnish cache on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish

I am finding out some of below question regrading cache.

What is radis cache and varnish cache?

Why we need to implement in Magento 2?

What major impact we are show in Magento 2 website?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Redis

[Redis](https://redis.io/) is a distributed key-value store that is massively scalable. It is used to store pre-computed values that can be retrieved at high speed and high concurrency.

Redis in Magento is used to offload the MySQL database. That's because the internal cost of running complex SQL queries on large databases is very high.

Even at minor scale, these SQL queries could lead to loading times of more than 2 seconds.

By storing pre-computed results in Redis, loading times remain acceptable.

Redis is also used to store Magento sessions.

### Varnish

[Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/) is a reverse caching proxy that is installed in front of your Magento server. Varnish caches complete HTTP responses and can offload your entire Magento application server.

Varnish is one of the world's fastest and most flexible HTTP caches and is a necessity for real-world Magento webshops.

> If you want to use Varnish on Magento, have a look at the following tutorial: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/configuring-varnish-magento/

### Redis vs Varnish

While both Redis and Varnish are caches, they serve an entirely different purpose.

- Redis offloads the database
- Varnish offloads the entire application

> While Varnish seems like the better solution based on this comparison, I would highly recommend installing both

For cacheable web pages like the catalog, the category pages and some CMS pages, Varnish will be a perfect fit. However, in a e-commerce context not all pages are cacheable. During the check-out procedure or when personalized content comes into play, Redis will prove its worth.

### Try it yourself

I would recommend that you set up a Magento without Redis & Varnish. Via tools like `ab` or `siege` you can do some load testing.

Check the results.

Then add Redis and run the same tests. Then add Varnish and compare the results.